# call dice contract's deposit method , Error 3050003: eosio_assert_message assertion failure

Tags: deposit

I encounter this problem when I call dice deposit token in the example contract。

```
root@ubuntu:/opt/eos# cleos push action dice deposit '[ "alice", "100.0000 EOS" ]' -p alice
Error 3050003: eosio_assert_message assertion failure
```

The console log is:

```
2018-08-05T09:49:36.388 thread-0   wasm_interface.cpp:929        eosio_assert         ] message: attempt to add asset with different symbol 
2018-08-05T09:49:36.388 thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:475           handle_exception     ] FC Exception encountered while processing chain.push_transaction
2018-08-05T09:49:36.389 thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:476           handle_exception     ] Exception Details: 3050003 eosio_assert_message_exception: eosio_assert_message assertion failure
assertion failure with message: attempt to add asset with different symbol
    {"s":"attempt to add asset with different symbol"}
    thread-0  wasm_interface.cpp:930 eosio_assert
pending console output: 
    {"console":""}
    thread-0  apply_context.cpp:61 exec_one
```

dice permission is:

```
root@ubuntu:/opt/eos# cleos get account dice
permissions: 
     owner     1:    1 EOS6zgn2DvsLD13ia6L4Lrnh1qCaC9ttSB757Q7DNh6p3n5qMyg2o
        active     1:    1 EOS6zgn2DvsLD13ia6L4Lrnh1qCaC9ttSB757Q7DNh6p3n5qMyg2o1 dice@eosio.code, 
memory: 
     quota:       unlimited  used:     340.8 KiB  

net bandwidth: 
     used:               unlimited
     available:          unlimited
     limit:              unlimited

cpu bandwidth:
     used:               unlimited
     available:          unlimited
     limit:              unlimited
```

alice permission is:

```
root@ubuntu:/opt/eos# cleos get account alice
permissions: 
     owner     1:    1 EOS6awyUE2cWm8h1Z4pgK2jBr47BsKWTJD2g3f8auPNYV4S5n67SV
        active     1:    1 EOS6awyUE2cWm8h1Z4pgK2jBr47BsKWTJD2g3f8auPNYV4S5n67SV1 dice@active, 
memory: 
     quota:       unlimited  used:     2.691 KiB  

net bandwidth: 
     used:               unlimited
     available:          unlimited
     limit:              unlimited

cpu bandwidth:
     used:               unlimited
     available:          unlimited
     limit:              unlimited



root@ubuntu:/opt/eos/contracts/dice# cleos get currency stats eosio.token eos
{
  "EOS": {
    "supply": "2000.0000 EOS",
    "max_supply": "1000000000.0000 EOS",
    "issuer": "eosio"
  }
}

root@ubuntu:/opt/eos/contracts/dice# cleos get currency balance eosio.token alice
1000.0000 EOS
```

Comment: try `SYS` instead of `EOS` in action arguments?

Comment: i tried and it's no work.

Answer (score 2):

On a local node, the default symbol is SYS, not EOS.
Try the following command:

```
cleos push action dice deposit '[ "alice", "100.0000 SYS" ]' -p alice
```

Make sure that you have enough SYS tokens.

I also see that the contents of your account are set up incorrectly, you should use `cleos system newaccount` instead of `cleos create account`.

Please see my BootBios script at https://github.com/PhillipHamnett/eos-boot-bios for a quick and easy developer setup